# iPad can navigation controller be put inside popover?

Tags: ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I have made popover displaying UITableViewController, that is used for navigation. What I am interested in to know is - can you use navigational controller inside popover. Lets say you have table where each row transitions to new view. Can this be used in conjuction with popover view, and if so, can you provide some working examples?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it's very much possible. Firstly create the object of your table class.

```
  TableClass *tblClassObj = [[TableClass alloc] init];
```

Then create the navigation controller object.

```
  UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tblClassObj];
```

Then use this navigatin controller for your pop over controller.

```
  UIPopoverController *samplePopOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navigationController];
  ...
```

Don't forget to release the objects.